# Firebase javascript promise in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, promise

I need to deploy a node.js server for some complicated business logic.

Is there any firebase library/module which allows me to use promises and not callbacks for the query and update/set methods?

I've found firebase-client, but it is based on REST.
Am much prefer one based on the javascript API, if there is one out there?

Thanks.

Comment: In addition to fireproof, several promise libraries can promisify libraries.

Comment: You can use the Bluebird promise library to automatically wrap an entire API in promises for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [Fireproof](https://github.com/casetext/fireproof).

Fireproof wraps Firebase objects with lightweight promise support.

```
var Fireproof = require('fireproof'),
  Firebase = require('firebase');

var fb = new Firebase('https://test.firebaseio.com/thing'),
  fp = new Fireproof(fb);

fireproof.auth('my_auth_token').then(function() {
  fp.child('path/to/data').then(...);
}, function(err) {
  console.error('Error authenticating to Firebase!');
})
```

Answer (score 3):

now they have integrated promises in firebase it self.
https://www.firebase.com/blog/2016-01-21-keeping-our-promises.html